# Javascript - JSON date formatting

Tags: javascript, json

With some help from some fellow stack users, I currently have this:

> http://jsfiddle.net/wZETP/

The JSON data gives me the {start.date} in YYYY-MM-DD formatting, but I would like to know how to implement a date change to:

> Mon 01 Jan

Comment: So, your real question is how do you format a date in javascript. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your date string `"2012-05-29"` to Date object:

```
var parts = date.split("-");
var d = new Date(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
```

Then use dateFormat from [here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format):

```
return d.format("ddd dd mmm");
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/riateche/wZETP/1/)

Comment: I believe you shouldn't need to split on the `date` variable. You should be able to just pass in `date` as-is using `new Date(date)`, and it will give you the correct date, assuming you ask for it in UTC.